# SSRS a combination of three different tables with similiar values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 3 tables

- The first table contains columns [membername], [id], [team]
- The second table has column [file name] with names of files for example "filename12345"
- And the third table contains columns [id] and [text] which have texts for example "yesterday i drop filename12345 to storage"

I used left join for tables 1 and 3 on [id]

Is any possibility to link these three tables together using the key word "filename12345"

I need this to make a report in report builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a LIKE in the JOIN to match the second table filenames up with the text in the third table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MEMBERS M 
JOIN TEXTS T ON T.ID = M.ID
JOIN FILES F ON F.FILENAME LIKE '%' + T.TEXT + '%'
```